# How can I change the circular photo on title bar of Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Every time I send an email, there is a circular photo associated with the message (top right). I cannot work out how to change this.

This is when I am using Apple's Mail.app on a MacBook running macOS Mojave 10.14.5. The image I cannot change is **not** my Google photo identity. This is an @gmail.com email ID.

Comment: What is the domain part (after @ symbol) of your email address?

Comment: the domain is @gmail.com

Comment: Is the picture shown associated with your Apple ID?

Comment: @NimeshNeema - yes it is, thank you!

Comment: Did you try re-adding the Gmail account in Mail app.

Comment: @NimeshNeema - thanks very much.  Sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-adding the Gmail account in Mail.app. This should resolve the issue.